# How was Walmart able to pop up an unsolicited "Rate your visit" notification on my phone?

Tags: privacy, smartphone

I was in Walmart this afternoon, and later this evening I noticed a strange icon in the upper left of the home screen on my android phone. On examination, I found a notification ostensibly from Walmart asking me to rate my visit, timestamped seven minutes after the timestamp on my receipt.

I have no Walmart-related apps on my phone, so how were they able to push a notification to it, let alone IDENTIFY it while I was in-store in such a way that would allow them to do so?

[image: screenshot of the unwanted Walmart notification]

Comment: This is from Google Maps iirc, which uses your device location (GPS, nearby Wifis, beacons) to track your phone.

Comment: @HenryF No, it's from Google Maps. You earn "points" as Google Guide and may earn more storage space because of this.

Answer (score 17):

***TL;DR:*** By **December 6th, 2018**, Google stopped serving *[Nearby Notifications](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html)*. Android users won't receiving this kind of notifications.

---

#### How were they able to push a notification?

As [@Martin Fürholz](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/148430/martin-f%c3%bcrholz) pointed out, that was came from Google Maps notification service. **Specifically**, from [Nearby Notifications](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview) feature that being developing by Google for the last years.

> #### Nearby Notifications Overview:
>
> Nearby Notifications helps users to discover what's around them, by surfacing location-specific notifications for apps and websites, **with no prior app install required**. Using Nearby Notifications, you can:
>
> 1. Drive your own app installs.
> 2. Open personal or business profiles in social apps.
> 3. Launch conversations or chatbots inside messaging apps.
> 4. Drive consumers to content about nearby products.
> 5. Help users explore store inventory.
> 6. Drive checkins, **reviews** within local/travel apps.
>
> *Neither experience requires that an app is installed on the user's device.*

([source](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview))

> #### How Nearby works:
>
> Nearby can use **small amounts of Wi-Fi or mobile data** to connect to Google and get info about broadcasts or shared apps.
>
> Nearby doesn’t track, monitor, or send personal info from your phone.
>
> - Nearby broadcasts are one-way, like over-the-air TV or radio.
>     Services that send Nearby signals don’t detect or get data from your
>     phone.
> - When you give permission, apps that work with Nearby share
>     with each other using remote servers. The sharing devices don’t
>     connect directly.

([source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6260286?hl=en))

#### How to disable Nearby Notifications?

1. Open your phone’s Settings app
2. Tap Google > Nearby > Settings
3. Under "Notification categories," tap a category.
4. Turn that notification type off.

([source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6260286?hl=en))

**Related articles:**

- [Google Maps now lets you quickly, and mindlessly, rate places from a notification](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/10/google-maps-now-lets-quickly-mindlessly-rate-places-notification/)
- [Google Maps for Android Lets Users Give Ratings to Places Directly From Notifications](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/google-maps-rating-notification-1881054)

---

***But*, keep in mind,** Google decided to discontinue support for Nearby Notifications. They'll stop serving Nearby Notifications on **December 6th, 2018**. [Learn more](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html).